# Adding asterisks to array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add elements as asterisks inside array based on number of elements. Basically If numberOfRows is 3 then I want this output:

```
[
  '  *  ', 
  ' *** ', 
  '*****'
]
```

I'm struggling on setting asterisks using the index. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Here's my code:

```js
function myFunction(numberOfRows) {

  var arr = [];
  var value = "";
  var asterisk = "*"; // Need to update this based on number of rows


  for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfRows; i++) {
    value += asterisk;
    arr.push(value);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: just a hint: `numAsterisk = i * 2 - 1`

Comment: it's enough to move outside the for loop:  **var asterisk = "*";**

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this;

```js
function myFunction(numberOfRows) {

  var arr = [];
  var value = "";
  var slots = numberOfRows * 2 - 1;
  var spaceSlots, asteriskSlots, spaces;

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
    asteriskSlots = i * 2 + 1;
    spaceSlots = Math.floor((slots - asteriskSlots)/2);
    spaces = new Array(spaceSlots).fill(' ').join('');
    value = spaces + '*'.repeat(asteriskSlots) + spaces;
    arr.push(value);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(myFunction(20));
```

Comment: Updated. `join('')`

Comment: Its not adding the empty spaces around the asterisks. Take a look at the output in my question

Comment: voting it up for the effort mate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got it working! Here's a perfect solution.

```js
function myFunction(n) {
  let arr = [];
  for(let f = 1; f <= n; f++) {
    arr.push(' '.repeat(n - f) + '*'.repeat(f + f - 1) + ' '.repeat(n - f));
  } 
  return arr;
}

console.log(myFunction(3));
```

Comment: Creating an n length array and mapping over it is a memory wasting way of counting to n.

Comment: It won't be as pretty to look at, but there's a whole bunch more waste that can be wrung out of this.  The identical padding on each side is built twice per iteration, the pad and star strings get created and discarded each iteration.  I'll post an alternative just to show what I mean...

Comment: Actually, I doubt what I've added is a very big win over this.  The only thing to change here, I think, is to not create the spaces padding twice in the loop.

Comment: Maybe a better idea would be to create an array of chars, use index math to poke stars into the middle and then join() on each iteration.